# Split 'designer' and 'source' windows on VS2017 Xamarin?

Tags: wpf, xaml, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I'm starting to develop apps on Xamarin, with Visual Studio 2017. As on WPF, there is a 'designer' window for the axml, with the view of the app itself, and a 'source' window with the xml describing the view.
My question is - can I split the windows so one will be above the other, just like as in WPF? Right now I can either view the designer or the source window.
Below are the wanted situation, and the current one. Thanks!
[image: WPF]

[image: Xamarin]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't support to achieve that in Xamarin.Android on Visual Studio 2017.
Event if you try to use the split view and place the design in your left side you can't put the source in your right.

I know it could be overkill but most of the times I use Android Studio to draw my layouts. Since it support viewing the source and designer.

Comment: Thanks :) Expected more from Xamarin, it seems less comfortable than WPF was. But we'll see...

Answer (score 0):

The split view designer feature for Xamarin Android has finally been added in the VS 2017 version 15.8 update. Here is  a link to the release notes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes

[Android Designer Split View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkEUI.png)

Comment: It was about time! Coming from Android Studio, WPF and Microsoft Blend, which had this for years now, I can't seem to understand how professional Xamarin app developers design their applications! Don't you need to see what UI element you're adding? It would be a hassle to build every time you want to see a change! Unless I am missing something. The Forms Previewer doesn't always seem to work either unfortunately.